# Web scraping of modal window(dialogue box) using jsoup

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsoup

I am studying about the project in which I have to extract the data from the website . The project is in java and the website is in java script . I am using Jsoup to extract the data from the website But there are some modal windows(dialogue box , pop up windows) present in the web page.So Is it possible to extract the data of modal windows using jsoup?????
 So if answer is yes , then how could I do it?? please provide links and if not, then what are the other best ways to do it???

Thanks for your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Do you have to run javascript to display the modal dialogs? If so, you cannot use Jsoup to display them since it doesn't support javascript. If they are visible without triggering the javascript, you can use Jsoup to parse it's content like normal.

Comment: So what should i use to extract data from modal window if they display by using the javascript.

Comment: I cannot say, since I do not know. All I know is that it isn't possible to use Jsoup to achieve it. You'll have to find a Java library that can execute javascript.

Comment: ok.thanks for your help.I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that the modal is generated by Javascript.
Jsoup is just a parser. This means that it will make an HTTP request (GET or POST, whatever you tell it to do) and the server (website) will respond with the initial html. By saying **initial**, I mean the html **before** any javascript is executed.

Javascript can generate html (like the modal in question), but this is not visible to Jsoup because a parser can only read, it cannot execute code. The browser is able to generate the modal because it includes a Javascript execution engine that parses **and** executes Javascript.

When you visit a web page you don't know what is dynamic (generated by Javascript) and what is static (fetched by the server as is).
A little trick to check what is dynamic and what is static (static is visible to Jsoup) is to do the following:

1. Visit the web page you want to parse (with chrome if possible, mozilla will work too I think).
2. Press Ctrl + U. This will open a new tab.

The new tab will contain some mesh of html, css and js. This is what the server fetches to the browser and is also visible to Jsoup.
If the modal is in there, then great, it is visible to Jsoup. If not, then you have to use a library that acts as a headless browser.

A headless browser is essentially a browser without the graphical interface. It can parse and execute Javascript. It "sees" what a normal browser sees.

The most common library used is [selenium webdriver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/). Be careful, selenium is a testing framework that has a lot of parts. What you need is the webdriver. 
There a lot of examples out there with ready made code to get you started.