# how to get button click popup values using jsoup in java

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm having trouble trying to parse the popup page values after button click of an element. Here is the case I am dealing with:

```
<button class="content id-view-permissions-details fake-link" data-docid="com.facebook.katana">
```

I am parsing the values from the endpoint: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.katana

How to get the "Permissions" from the above button tag??

Comment: you can definitely find something useful here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31428143/web-scraping-of-modal-windowdialogue-box-using-jsoup

Comment: the content there appears only after you click a button (ajax or something) and jsoup is basically a parser of html that you have or can GET

Answer (score 0):

given that button as an Element named btn, you can go with

```
btn.previousElementSibling().text()
```